# CakePHP 2.x : Cascade delete with softdelete do not work

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, soft-delete

I use softdelete Behaviour of [Utils Plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/tree/2.0-tests) for CakePHP 2.x

I have following 4 tables

1. customers
2. customer_addresses
3. customer_contacts
4. customer_reports

And consider following its relationship with each other,

**1. for customers**

Customer hasMany CustomerAddress

Customer hasMany CustomerContact

Customer hasMany CustomerReport

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'CustomerAddress' => array(
        'className' => 'CustomerAddress',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        ),
    'CustomerContact' => array(
        'className' => 'CustomerContact',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        ),
    'CustomerReport' => array(
        'className' => 'CustomerReport',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        )
);
```

**2. for customer_addresses**

CustomerAddress belongsTo Customer

CustomerAddress belongsTo State

CustomerAddress hasOne CustomerContact

CustomerAddress hasOne CustomerReport

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Customer' => array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        ),
    'State' => array(
        'className' => 'State',
        'foreignKey' => 'state_id',
        )
);
public $hasOne = array(
    'CustomerContact' => array(
        'className' => 'CustomerContact',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_address_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        ),
    'CustomerReport' => array(
        'className' => 'CustomerReport',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_address_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        )
);
```

**3. for customer_contacts**

CustomerContact belongsTo Customer

CustomerContact belongsTo CustomerAddress

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Customer' => array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        ),
    'CustomerAddress' => array(
        'className' => 'CustomerAddress',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_address_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        )
);
```

**4. for customer_reports**

CustomerReport  belongsTo  Customer

CustomerReport  belongsTo  CustomerAddress

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Customer' => array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        ),
    'CustomerAddress' => array(
        'className' => 'CustomerAddress',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_address_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        )

);
```

I have put below code in bootstrap.

```
CakePlugin::load('Utils');
```

I have also added below actAs in all above model

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable','Utils.SoftDelete');
```

I have already put below code in my appModel.

```
// for softdelete, checking exist id
public function exists($id = null) {
    if ($this->Behaviors->attached('SoftDelete')) {
        return $this->existsAndNotDeleted($id);
    } else {
        return parent::exists($id);
    }
}
// for softdelete, overrite delete method
public function delete($id = null, $cascade = true) {
    $result = parent::delete($id, $cascade);
    if ($result === false && $this->Behaviors->enabled('SoftDelete')) {
       return $this->field('deleted', array('deleted' => 1));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**When I try to cascade delete with out soft delete ( means simple cascade delete ) , it works fine.
But My problem is that.
When I use softdelete behaviour of [Utils plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/tree/2.0-tests) , Cascade delete does not work.**

I have tried to delete record using below code

```
if ($this->CustomerAddress->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('CustomerAddress deleted'));
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
```

**SQL log**

```
array(
'log' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'query' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `lewie`.`customer_addresses` AS `CustomerAddress` LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`customers` AS `Customer` ON (`CustomerAddress`.`customer_id` = `Customer`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`states` AS `State` ON (`CustomerAddress`.`state_id` = `State`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`customer_contacts` AS `CustomerContact` ON (`CustomerContact`.`customer_address_id` = `CustomerAddress`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`customer_reports` AS `CustomerReport` ON (`CustomerReport`.`customer_address_id` = `CustomerAddress`.`id`)  WHERE `CustomerAddress`.`id` = 43 AND `CustomerAddress`.`deleted` = '0'',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 0
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'query' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `lewie`.`customer_addresses` AS `CustomerAddress` LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`customers` AS `Customer` ON (`CustomerAddress`.`customer_id` = `Customer`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`states` AS `State` ON (`CustomerAddress`.`state_id` = `State`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`customer_contacts` AS `CustomerContact` ON (`CustomerContact`.`customer_address_id` = `CustomerAddress`.`id` AND `CustomerContact`.`deleted` = '0') LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`customer_reports` AS `CustomerReport` ON (`CustomerReport`.`customer_address_id` = `CustomerAddress`.`id` AND `CustomerReport`.`deleted` = '0')  WHERE `CustomerAddress`.`id` = 43 AND `CustomerAddress`.`deleted` = '0'',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 1
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'query' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `lewie`.`customer_addresses` AS `CustomerAddress` LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`customers` AS `Customer` ON (`CustomerAddress`.`customer_id` = `Customer`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`states` AS `State` ON (`CustomerAddress`.`state_id` = `State`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`customer_contacts` AS `CustomerContact` ON (`CustomerContact`.`customer_address_id` = `CustomerAddress`.`id` AND `CustomerContact`.`deleted` = '0') LEFT JOIN `lewie`.`customer_reports` AS `CustomerReport` ON (`CustomerReport`.`customer_address_id` = `CustomerAddress`.`id` AND `CustomerReport`.`deleted` = '0')  WHERE `CustomerAddress`.`id` = 43 AND `CustomerAddress`.`deleted` = '0'',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 0
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'query' => 'UPDATE `lewie`.`customer_addresses` SET `deleted` = '1', `deleted_date` = '2014-05-27 10:46:43', `modified` = '2014-05-27 10:46:43'  WHERE `lewie`.`customer_addresses`.`id` = '43'',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 0
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        'query' => 'SELECT `CustomerAddress`.`deleted` FROM `lewie`.`customer_addresses` AS `CustomerAddress`   WHERE `deleted` = '1'    LIMIT 1',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 0
    )
),
'count' => (int) 5,
'time' => (float) 1)
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: @AD7six : I use $this->CustomerAddress->delete()  for delete record.I have not any error.It delete only from cutomer_addresses table but not works cascade delete

Comment: @AD7six : I have edited code for 1.remove all the default array values , 2.how i am trying to delete records, 3.sql log. Please look at.

Comment: Ok much better. So "doesn't work" means that the related records aren't deleted at all (that wasn't obvious). Your app model beforeDelete function conflicts with [the behavior logic](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/2.0-tests/Model/Behavior/SoftDeleteBehavior.php#L122-L132) - you are attempting to delete the same row twice. The behavior apparently doesn't handle the `$cascade` property - so "the fix" would be to call delete on the relevant associated model, in a loop, yourself, which will mean you won't really be using the soft delete behavior at all.

Comment: @AD7six : How can I resolve this confliction of beforeDelete?

Comment: The soft delete behavior doesn't handle cascading deletes (which I would consider a bug). So, one way or another, you need to implement it yourself - ideally as a patch for the behavior you're using but otherwise by defining delete in your CustomerAddress model to delete the records you want it to.